# What happened to the golden eggs retrieved during the first task in Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

In the fourth book, *Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire*, all four champions retrieve a single golden egg from their randomly assigned dragon. We see that with Cedric's hint, Harry submerges his, in the Prefects' bathroom, and hears the song about the second task.

All that said and good, but what happened to all those eggs? Has Rowling said anything about those eggs and what happened to them after the Triwizard tournament?

Comment: Omlet?.........

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The last time we see it is when Harry puts it into his trunk in Chapter 25.

> And Moody thought he, Harry, ought to be an Auror! Interesting idea …
> but as Harry got quietly into his four-poster ten minutes later, **the
> egg and the Cloak now safely back in his trunk,** he somehow thought
> he’d like to check how scarred the rest of them were, before he chose
> it as a career.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire (Chapter 25 - The Egg and the Eye)*</sup></sub>

History does not record its fate after this. Presumably it was either returned to the Department of Magical Games and Sports, or kept by Harry (or Hogwarts) as a souvenir of the event.

---

Out of universe, Rupert Grint <s>tried to steal it</s> briefly borrowed it, but was spotted by one of the film's prop masters who asked for it to be returned, noting that they cost about $10,000 each to make.

Comment: $10,000 seems quite unlikely. Even the "hero" one that opens us is still mostly resin, cardboard, and gold paint.

Comment: @OrangeDog - That's what he said in the clip, and I'm going to go with that

Comment: It's 'cause the current exchange rate between Galleons and Dollars is just crazy.

Comment: that $10,000 could also be accounting for person-hours in the creation of the hero props as well as materials. Assuming, let's say a 9-hour day, and oh, 5 people (paint, sculpt, assembly, etc...) the math may break down to around $150 an hour or so which seems a reasonable cost - excluding materials. I of course have no industry knowledge so the entire formula could be as valid as any other JKR maths

Comment: Inflating the cost of props is one aspect of Hollywood accounting. Every dollar "spent" on production costs is one less dollar to be shared with the people who signed for a piece of the net.

Comment: It's odd that the $10,000 number is what's being questioned, if anything that's an underestimate. We're all used to mass produced toys, but custom built prop manufacturing is expensive.

Comment: @BradyGilg - Especially 'hero' props with self-moving parts, that are robust enough to be handled by kids.

Comment: @EvilSnack Kind of like how tax write-offs work, or how the US defense department can just send $6B more dollars out with a simple "cost adjustment" on a spread sheet. Accrual accounting ought to be added to the "lies, damned lies, and statistics" slogan.

Answer (score 13):

If we are to take Moody (Crouch Jr.) seriously, then the eggs belonged to the champions:

***Goblet of Fire* Chapter Twenty-Five**

> “No!” said Filch, clutching the egg as though it were his firstborn son.
> “Professor Moody, this is evidence of Peeves’ treachery!”
>
> “It’s the
> property of the champion he stole it from,” said Moody. “Hand it over,
> now.”

Thus, the champions presumably still have them, unless they sold/lost/gifted/etc. them.

Comment: If we take him at his literal word, the egg is the property of the champion. But after they stop being the champion, it presumably stops being their property...

Comment: @Valorum "Champion" can also mean "someone who competes on another's behalf". Fleur would be Beauxbatons' champion (representative) even if she never won anything.

Comment: @R.M. - After the competition, they would be a '*former champion*'

Comment: @Valorum Are you actually quibbling that Filch should have said "former" champion in this scene, with takes place not long after the tournament finishes, quite chaotically?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - It's more a quibble with the statement that the egg **must still be in his possession because he's the champion.**